# I want to pass variables from C#(ASP.NET 4.5) button event to a JQuery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have been trying to learn how to pass variables from a C# method in my page, to a JQuery DateTimePicker. My C# works fine, but I cannot find a good tutorial that relates to the specific task of passing my DateTime value from C# to the JQuery DateTimePicker. I have looked on here and tried a few things, but they don't work.

I am not expecting anyone to solve it for me, I am asking for a good and solid tutorial about passing data from C# to JQuery functions, specifically around datetime, so I can solve it myself.

I have tried the JQuery site and could not find anything.

Thanks in advance.

The current DTP Jquery  code is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                            $( function ()
                            {
                                $( '#datetimepickerFrom' ).datetimepicker( {
                                    format: 'DD/MM/YY HH:mm',
                                    stepping: 30,
                                    toolbarPlacement: "bottom",
                                    showTodayButton: true,
                                    showClear: true,
                                    collapse: true
                                } );

                                $( '#datetimepickerTo' ).datetimepicker( {
                                    format: 'DD/MM/YY HH:mm',
                                    stepping: 30,
                                    toolbarPlacement: "bottom",
                                    showTodayButton: true,
                                    showClear: true,
                                } );
                                $( "#datetimepickerFrom" ).on( "dp.change", function ( e )
                                {
                                    $( '#datetimepickerFrom' ).data( "DateTimePicker" ).minDate( e.date );
                                } );

                                $( "#datetimepickerTo" ).on( "dp.change", function ( e )
                                {
                                    $( '#datetimepickerTo' ).data( "DateTimePicker" ).maxDate( e.date );
                                } );
                            } );

    $( "input[id$='btnMonth']" ).click( function ()
                            {
                                var MonthFrom = $( "#HiddenMonthFrom" ).val();
                                var MonthTo = $( "#HiddenMonthTo" ).val();
                                alert( MonthFrom + " to " + MonthTo );
                                $( '#datetimepickerTo' ).data( "DateTimePicker" ).setDate(MonthFrom);                          
                            } );
```

I have added this and can now get the data from hidden fields:

The C# code is from a button on the web page.

```
    protected void btnYesterday_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        DateTime b = a.GetYesterDayDateTimeFrom();//Gets the from date and time eg: Yesterday at 4pm
        DateTime c = a.DateTo();//Is the date to value eg: tomorrow at 3pm
        //Here is where I want to pass the dates to the JQuery DTP
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a static value for from date and to date When the page loads? If that is the case, then have two hidden input fields that will store these fromDate and toDate on page load and when the button is clicked, instead of going back to code behind btnYesterday_Click() function, call a js function in the same page which will then grab the values stored earlier in the hidden input fields.

Comment: I want to do the update of the date fields with the click event. The date values when the page first loads are empty. So if I put two hidden fields and use the button event to assign the values to those, I can then use the JQuery to take those values. Can this be done dynamically, or does the page have to reload each time?

Comment: You can do this dynamically. You should look at the, asp:UpdatePanel for this

Comment: I have added the hiddenfields and can now get the data thanks. It works a charm. The problem is the datetime picker will not change it's date when I click on the button.click function. I have tried setDate, Update and looked on GitHub, any ideas? I added the edit in the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using my picker change your code to use [`date([newDate])`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#date)

```
$( "input[id$='btnMonth']" ).click(function ()
{
    var MonthFrom = $( "#HiddenMonthFrom" ).val();
    var MonthTo = $( "#HiddenMonthTo" ).val();
    alert( MonthFrom + " to " + MonthTo );
    $('#datetimepickerTo').data("DateTimePicker").date(MonthFrom);                          
});
```

Comment: I tried every permutation but the obvious one. You sir are a gentleman and a scholar...All the best